# How can i exclude few database columns from displaying in object list view in Django

Tags: django-models, django-views

I use this function to get list of all objects

```
 object_list = Author.objects.all()
```

But  there are many fields which i don't want to display . how can hide them

As i loop throgh all fields so i cant check in template. i need to do it model or view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [values_list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) or [values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) methods. Both accepts optional *fields arguments, so you can specify which fields you need.

```
>>> Entry.objects.values_list('id', 'headline')
[(1, u'First entry'), ...]
```

I am not quite sure that i've understood the question right, so if you'll expand it a little (maybe some more code) - answer may be more concrete.

Comment: i want what u have wriiten but i need query set , is there any was

Comment: Sorry, Was wrong - actualy this methods return ValuesQuerySet - subset of QuerySet, so it could be filtered and so on, but returns dictionaries/lists when used as an iterable...   If it's still not what you wanted, please, provide more info.